# using pointer for multidemsional array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a pointer to 4dimensional array; and I want to use it to assign values to 4 dimensional array.

What I know is to create a 4 dimensional array and traverse through it using pointer to float

```
float dArray [2][3][4][5];
float *ptr = &dArray[0][0][0][0];
```

What I am struggling with is if I have pointer to 4dimensional array

```
float ***pointerArray4D[];
```

and say I want to use it store values in it for below array - how do I do it.

```
value = 0;
for (int ix0 = 0; ix0 < DIM0; ++ix0)
 for (int ix1 = 0; ix1 < DIM1; ++ix1)
  for (int ix2 = 0; ix2 < DIM2; ++ix2)
   for (int ix3 = 0; ix3 < DIM3; ++ix3)
    pointerArray4D[ix0][ix1][ix2][ix3] = float(value++);
```

What I have tried to do is

1)

```
float pointerArray4D_1[2][3][4][5];
float ***pointerArray4D[5];
pointerArray4D = pointerArray4D_1;
```

2) Other thing which i think I should be doing is assign memory to it

```
pointerArray4D=new float*[2]; 
for(int i=0; i<2; ++i)
    pointerArray4D[i]=new float*[3];
for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    pointerArray4D[i]=new float*[4];
for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    pointerArray4D[i]=new float[5];
```

error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘=’ token

Needless to say a new bee learning the art :)

Edited - the typo of using double to represent the idea of I being able to traverse

Answer (score 0):

This ...

```
double dArray [2][3][4][5];
```

... declares an array.  There is storage for 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 `double`s associated with it.

This ...

```
float ***pointerArray4D[];
```

... declares a an array of unspecified length of `float ***`, where it's in fact legal at all (that is, at file scope).  That's effectively the same as a `float ****`. There is no associated storage for any actual `float`s until and unless you allocate some.  Moreover, the space you allocate for `pointerArray4D` would be expected to hold values of type `float ***` (per its declaration).  You can work with this, but you'd have to perform four levels of allocation.

Supposing `DIM0` - `DIM3` to be preprocessor macros, you maybe want something like this, instead:

```
float (*pointerArray4D)[DIM1][DIM2][DIM3];

pointerArray4D = malloc(DIM0 * sizeof(*pointerArray4D));
```

... after which you can handle `pointerArray4D` exactly as you would do `dArray`.  (But don't forget to `free(pointerArray4D)` when you're done with it.)

Comment: Note that this answer assumes C, which is not the same thing as C++.

Comment: `float ***pointerArray4D[];` does not declare a `float ****`.  In C++ it's illegal. In C it is legal at file scope and is a tentative definition of an array of `float ***`, however OP seems to be using it at block scope anyway.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I did note already that my answer pertains to C, not C++.  With regard to C, cdecl calls `float ***pointerArray4D[]` the declaration of an *array* of `float ***`, which decays to `float ****`, not `float ***`.  I admit to some imprecision there, but for most intents and purposes, `float ****` can be used in place of `float ***pointerArray4D[]` anywhere the latter is allowed in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, following the hint of user3353819:

> think of `double array[a][b][c][d]` as simply an array of doubles of
>   length a * b * c * d. This means you would find the first element with
>   `&array` which is of type `double*`

Looking at your code:

```
float ***pointerArray4D[];
value = 0;
for (int ix0 = 0; ix0 < DIM0; ++ix0)
 for (int ix1 = 0; ix1 < DIM1; ++ix1)
  for (int ix2 = 0; ix2 < DIM2; ++ix2)
   for (int ix3 = 0; ix3 < DIM3; ++ix3)
    pointerArray4D[ix0][ix1][ix2][ix3] = float(value++);
```

the right way to do it is:

```
float fArray[DIM0][DIM1][DIM2][DIM3];
float *pointerArray = &fArray[0][0][0][0];
float fValue = 0;
for (int ix0 = 0; ix0 < DIM0; ++ix0)
 for (int ix1 = 0; ix1 < DIM1; ++ix1)
  for (int ix2 = 0; ix2 < DIM2; ++ix2)
   for (int ix3 = 0; ix3 < DIM3; ++ix3)
    pointerArray[ ix0*DIM1*DIM2*DIM3 + ix1*DIM2*DIM3 + ix2*DIM3 + ix3 ] = fValue++;
```

The key is that the array having dimension of [DIM0][DIM1][DIM2][DIM3] is a contiguos space 
in memory that hold "DIM0 times a block containing" "DIM1 times a block containing" "DIM2 times a block containing" "DIM3 times a float"

As esemplification the following code give the same result:

```
float fArray[DIM0][DIM1][DIM2][DIM3];
float *pointerArray = &fArray[0][0][0][0];
float fValue = 0;
for (int ix0 = 0; ix0 < DIM0; ++ix0)
 for (int ix1 = 0; ix1 < DIM1; ++ix1)
  for (int ix2 = 0; ix2 < DIM2; ++ix2)
   for (int ix3 = 0; ix3 < DIM3; ++ix3)
    *pointerArray++ = fValue++;
```

or even better:

```
float fArray[DIM0][DIM1][DIM2][DIM3];
float *pointerArray = &fArray[0][0][0][0];
float fValue = 0;
const int nElem = DIM0*DIM1*DIM2*DIM3;
for (int ix = nElem; ix>0; --ix)
   *pointerArray++ = fValue++;
```

Hoping this answer you question, have a good night, Stefano

Comment: @MattMcNabb, `fArray[0][0][0][0];` is a `float`, `&fArray[0][0][0][0];` is an address to a `float`. It compiles.